# How to use variables in dot notation to find child relationship name?

Tags: sobject, dynamic, variable

Instead of **teacher__c** and **student__c**, they needs be dynamic variables. How can I substitute these API names with variables: `parentApiName` and `childApiName`?

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.teacher__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == student__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

What I tried and failed:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.${parentApiName}.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == `${childApiName}.sObjectType`)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Schema information dynamically by leveraging some of the dynamic Schema methods like `describeSObjects` which takes a list of strings. I've taken your code and written a method that accepts the parent type and child type dynamically and returns the relationship name, if one exists.

```java
public static String getRelationshipName(String parentObjectApiNames, String childObjectApiName)
    List<Schema.DescribeSObjectResult> result = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{parentObjectApiNames});

    for (ChildRelationship relation : result[0].getChildRelationships()) {
        if (relation.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getName() == childObjectApiName) {
            return relation.getRelationshipName();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: @ nbrown Works great thanks!

Comment: Good to hear! If this answers your question then please accept it. Also, it's worth noting that schema methods can be resource intensive at times, so this method is a prime candidate for memoization so that way, should you need to call it multiple times, you don't need to walk all of the relationships on an object and instead put them all in a map for subsequent calls.